# why Ghost node_modules is much larger on openshift than on local?

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift, node-modules, ghost-blog

I'using Openshift to deploy my Ghost blog. **My whole code package is about 80m (including production node_modules, which is about 24m), mysql file is about 50m. Openshift shows me a warning message that I have used 97% of the total 1GB. How does this happen?** If it's normal, I'm willing to upgrade it, but I want to figure out if I have done something wrong.

I check folder size using SSH, `du -m --max-depth=1` got folder size results of my root folder like this:

```
1       ./.node-gyp
1       ./nodejs
du: cannot read directory `./.ssh': Permission denied
1       ./.ssh
du: cannot read directory `./.sandbox': Permission denied
1       ./.sandbox
52      ./mysql
1       ./.gem
1       ./.openshift_ssh
1       ./.auth
1       ./phpmyadmin
58      ./git
334     ./app-root
du: cannot read directory `./.tmp': Permission denied
1       ./.tmp
1       ./.env
325     ./app-deployments
768     .
```

**Does app-deployments save one previous version of app-root?** I found a folder with commit date as folder name.

Then for app-root folder:

```
4       ./logs
5       ./data
325     ./runtime
334     .
```

For runtime folder:

```
140     ./dependencies
1       ./build-dependencies
186     ./repo
325     .
```

For repo folder:

```
1       ./.openshift
7       ./core
5       ./content
175     ./node_modules
186     .
```

for dependencies folder, **what is dependencies folder used for?**

```
1       ./nodejs
140     ./.npm
140     .
```

Is the npm folder the global folder for npm? **when I have node_modules in my project, why it still install it to glocal? Can I change it?**

Then in node_modules, I saw `bower` module which is defined in `devDependencies` in package.json.

**I set env var for openshift to be production, why everything in devDependencies still in there?**

NODE_ENV=production
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true

**How can I remove those extra modules and save some disk space?**

Answer (score 0):

> My whole code package is about 80m (including production node_modules,
>   which is about 24m), mysql file is about 50m. Openshift shows me a
>   warning message that I have used 97% of the total 1GB. How does this
>   happen?

This may seem like an obvious answer but hang in there. That message means that your storage quota is 97% full. While your code may only be a small portion of that, there are several other things that use storage on the OpenShift Gear. For instance, app-deployments (see below) can sometimes take a significant amount of storage. So can things in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (~/app-root/data).

> Does app-deployments save one previous version of app-root?

Yes this feature allows you to easily roll back to an earlier version of your application. The downside is that it can consume a lot of your default storage. You can disable this though with

`rhc app configure <appname> -keep-deployments 0`

> when I have node_modules in my project, why it still install it to
>   glocal? Can I change it?

Node modules at this time can't be installed globally so they have to be installed locally within your gear.

> I set env var for openshift to be production, why everything in
>   devDependencies still in there?

This has to do with the way containers work. Everything you do is stored within your secure container. Setting the production environment variable just changes the way node starts

> How can I remove those extra modules and save some disk space?

You could try using npm to remove some of them on your gear but I would recommend that you just save yourself the trouble and either get rid of app deployments mentioned above or just upgrade.

Comment: I get the error:
```Invalid number of deployments to keep: 0. Keep deployments must be greater than 0 and no greater than 1000.```